# Testing with phpunit a try catch store method to test the exception

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, phpunit

I want to test this function:

```
public function store(array $input){

        \DB::beginTransaction();

        try{

            $input['name'] = $input['first_name'].$input['last_name'];
            $input['password'] = str_random(7);

            $user = $this->model->create($input);

            $role_user = new RoleUser();
            $role_user->role_id = $input['role_id'];
            $role_user->user_id = $user->id;
            $role_user->save();

            \DB::commit();

            return $user;

        }catch (Exception $e){

            \DB::rollback();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Here is my Test

```
/** @test */
    public function testUserRepoStoreFail()
    {
        $roleUser = factory(\App\Models\RoleUser::class)->create();
        $role = factory(\App\Models\Role::class)->create();

        $this->expectException(Exception::class);

        $data =[
            'role_id' => $role->id,
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'first_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'last_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
            'remember_token' => str_random(10),
        ];

        $rep = new UserRepositoryEloquent($this->container);
//
        $user = $rep->store($data);


    }
```

I remove the email to get the store function to fail

When I do this I get:

> 1) Tests\Unit\AuthTest::testUserRepoStoreFail Failed asserting that exception of type "Exception" is thrown.**

Comment: This is basically saying that you are expecting an exception using `$this->expectException(Exception::class)`, however when you use the `store()` method, not exception is being thrown.

Comment: Also, if you did not, say `use Exception;` at the top of your classes, just after the namespace, or use `\Exception` instead of `Exception` in the catch() and in your test assertion. If you don't do one of these, your exception namespace will be the same as the class where it's being used and the two exceptions won't match

Answer (score 2):

Even if an exception is thrown it is catched and handles within the `store`-method. `expectException` expects an unhandled exception.
If you want to test the catch-block in your method you have to assert that `DB::rollback()` was called or simply that the method returns `false` instead of a user-instance.

Answer (score 0):

The test is not passing probably because no Exception is thrown when you miss the email. Check whether are you getting any Exception when you do a manual test. If not try to add an Exception yourself like this:

```
public function store(array $input){

        \DB::beginTransaction();

        try{

            $input['name'] = $input['first_name'].$input['last_name'];
            $input['password'] = str_random(7);

            //Add this check
            if(empty($input['email'])){
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Email is empty");
            }

            $user = $this->model->create($input);

            $role_user = new RoleUser();
            $role_user->role_id = $input['role_id'];
            $role_user->user_id = $user->id;
            $role_user->save();

            \DB::commit();

            return $user;

        }catch (Exception $e){

            \DB::rollback();
            return false;
        }

    }
```